# Rails - uninitialized constant Post (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a script in my lib folder called flow.rb This file is run as a background process.

In my file I am trying to create posts:

```
@post = Post.new
```

But I get this error

```
uninitialized constant Post (NameError)
```

What is causing this. Do I have to import or require activerecord?

Comment: Have you tried to require activerecord in your file?

Comment: Yes, that does not work. I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Start you script with the `rails runner`:

```
rails runner flow.rb
```

Or require the Rails environment in your script with:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much Martin!!